# How to get product link in magento admin product edit?

Tags: magento-1.8, product

Is it possible to get product link in admin product edit section ?

Comment: the frontend link or the backend link?

Comment: @Marius ,front-end link of that product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frontend link of a product depends on the store id. 
So you can have different urls for different store views.

Here is an example:

```
$storeId = 1;
$productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
$url = $product->getProductUrl();
```

If you want the url in a category try this:

```
$storeId = 1;
$productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
if (isset($categoryIds[0])) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($categoryIds[0]);
    Mage::register('current_category', $category);
}
$url = $product->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: I am getting url like http://127.0.0.1/aseo2/index.php/htc-touch-diamond.html?___store=default .But i need to display as http://127.0.0.1/aseo2/index.php/electronics/cell-phones/htc-touch-diamond.html . Is it possible

Comment: It's possible but not that easy. A product can be associated to many categories and have a different url depending on the current category. For the backend there is no current category. I will try to see what I can do,

Comment: @Anu. See my updated answer. But I'm not sure you will always get the right results.